# How to manipulate HTML elements in Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

Let's say I have this table:

[image]

I'd like to `check` the **top checkbox** and have all them checked, or `uncheck` it then have all of them **unchecked**.

In JQuery, something like this:

```
$("#mytable tbody :checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

You can also find a checkbox and applied change to it.

I just don't see how to establish 2-ways binding with those checkboxex as they are dynamically constructed.

```
<tr *ngFor="let tRow of initConsView.bodyData">
  <td *ngFor="let col of tRow">
    <input *ngIf="col.key == 'Id'" 
            type="checkbox" [attr.id]="'ck_' + col.value"                                                        
            (change)="onChecked($event, col.value)" />                                                
    <span *ngIf="col.key != 'Id'">{{ col.value }}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Do I need to keep track of each chekbox through an array of ids, representing each checkbox?

With one checkbox, I could do something like this:

```
[checked]="someValueInTheTypeScriptFile"
```

I've though about using nested component containing a checkbox. Unfortunately, the problem remains the same. In fact, it will be easy to send data from component to container. However, targeting some or all  the checkbox is what's a little challenging.

Thanks for helping

Comment: looking for some thing like [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/h9wFGz/)

Comment: you should probably use forms for working with checkboxes

Comment: @RahulSingh, yes.

Comment: @Richard77 i see you have an accepted answer hope it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the angular way, you should definitely use bindings for this. Every row need to have something like an `isChecked` property that is used for the  `[(ngModel)]="isChecked"` binding.

The *top checkbox* will then trigger a method that loops through all your items used for populating the checkbox list and set their `isChecked` property to either `true` or `false`.

*In the template*

```
<!-- Top checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheckTop($event.target.checked)" />  

<!-- Other checkboxes -->
<tr *ngFor="let tRow of initConsView.bodyData">
  <td *ngFor="let col of tRow">
    <input *ngIf="col.key == 'Id'" 
           type="checkbox" [attr.id]="'ck_' + col.value"                                                        
           (change)="onChecked($event, col.value)"
           <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->  
           [(ngModel)]="tRow.isChecked" /> <!-- Add this -->  
           <!-- ---------------------------------------- -->                                              
    <span *ngIf="col.key != 'Id'">{{ col.value }}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

*In the TS file*

```
onCheckTop(check: boolean) {
  this.initConsView.bodyData.forEach(data => data.isChecked = check);
}
```

*In your `ngModule`* make sure to add the `FormsModule` so you can use the `[(ngModel)]` directive in your template

```
// Other imports
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., FormsModule ],
  ....
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I think this way, I'll be able to even remember which individual rows user selected, and be able to check the checkbox when the page loads. Thank you so much.